# Android SQLite DB Error

Tags: android, sqlite

i have an android App which uses an SQLite Database. In one Activity the User can add a String and two Values.
This should be added by following code.

```
    public void insertValue(SQLiteDatabase db, String type, String value1, String value2){
    String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO history (_id , calcType , value1 , value2) VALUES (" + null +", "+ type +", "+  value1 +", "+  value2 + ")";
    try {
        db.execSQL(insertSQL);
    }catch(SQLException e){
        Log.d("INSERT FAILURE", e.toString());
    }
}
```

If i enter manually a value to "calcType" the following error occurs. If enter "null" no error occurs and the whole sql statement works.

```
    09-18 13:42:51.124: I/Database(1244): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: radius
    09-18 13:42:51.124: E/Database(1244): Failure 1 (no such column: radius) on 0x2a2900 when preparing 'INSERT INTO history (_id , calcType , value1 , value2) VALUES (null, radius, 34, 77)'.
    09-18 13:42:51.124: D/INSERT INTO FAILURE(1244):android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: radius: INSERT INTO history (_id , calcType , value1 , value2) VALUES (null, radius, 34, 77)
```

The Database is created with this String:

```
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_HISTORY = 
            "CREATE TABLE history(" + 
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
            "calcType TEXT, " +
            "value1 TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            "value2 TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
```

I have no idea whats wrong with the Insert SQL Statemant or the Table listed above.

Comment: use the `insert` method, that'll prevent this kind of issue by taking care of escaping the values for you. (the error is that you are not escaping the values, and sql understands the litteral radius string as a column name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

njkz2 is right in his comment. You need to escape the values. To get the code you have running, change it like so:

```
String insertSQL = (String)"INSERT INTO history (_id , calcType , value1 , value2) VALUES (" + null +", '"+ type +"', '"+  value1 +"', '"+  value2 + "')";
```

Be aware that this is susceptible to sql injection attacks, and will break if one of the values contains a single quote (').

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now it works! Maybe i will use the insert method njzk2 mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of casting and also when you pass values to TEXT field you must enclose with single qoutes

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO history (_id , calcType , value1 , value2) VALUES (" + null +", '"+ type +"', '"+  value1 +"', '"+  value2 + "')";
```